# (C) Organize integer array using two pointers

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to organize an array in increasing and decreasing order *without neither changing its original position nor creating a new one*. The point is: I gotta use only two pointers to do so. Since they both, increasing and decreasing order, are analogue, I'm focusing on the increasing function.

My algorithm looks like an Insertion Sort type. But, instead of going through all the array, and then going backwards to make sure everthing is OK, I coded so as it goes one step ahead, and then take a look at all the one behind. If the previous element is fitted in the right position, then it doesn't have to check the others, then it breaks the lace:

> for(;z>0;z--)

I'm not pretty sure of what's going on anymore. For instance, the output of "-8 10 2 0" is:

Include integers in the array:
-8 10 2 0

array: original.

Integer: -8 || Address: 0x7ffc88143d20

Integer: 10 || Address: 0x7ffc88143d24

Integer: 2 || Address: 0x7ffc88143d28

Integer: 0 || Address: 0x7ffc88143d2c

Increasing order:

Integer:    2||last_shown: -8

Integer:    0||last_shown: 2

Integer:    -2011939296||last_shown: 0

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4
void get_data(int *array)
{
    int i;
    printf("Include integers in the array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
}
void shows_original(int *array)
{
    int i;
    printf("array: original.\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("Integer: %d || Address: %p\n", array[i], &array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void increasing_order(int* DataArray)
{
    int i, z;
    int *current_ptr = DataArray, *last_shown = DataArray;
    printf("Increasing order:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        z = i;
        if (DataArray[i + 1] >= DataArray[i] && *current_ptr >= *last_shown)
        {
            current_ptr = &DataArray[i];
            for (; z > 0; z--)
            {
                if (*current_ptr >= DataArray[z - 1])
                {
                    if (&DataArray[z - 1] == last_shown)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        last_shown = current_ptr;
                        current_ptr = &DataArray[z - 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            last_shown = current_ptr;
        }
        else if (DataArray[i + 1] < DataArray[i] && *current_ptr >= *last_shown)
        {
            current_ptr = &DataArray[i + 1];
            for (z; z > 0; z--)
            {
                if (*current_ptr >= DataArray[z - 1])
                {
                    if (&DataArray[z - 1] == last_shown)
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        last_shown = current_ptr;
                        current_ptr = &DataArray[z - 1];
                    }
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            printf("Integer:    %d||last_shown: %d\n", *current_ptr,
                    *last_shown);
            last_shown = current_ptr;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int DataArray[N];
    get_data(DataArray);
    shows_original(DataArray);
    increasing_order(DataArray);
    /*decreasing_order(DataArray);*/
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me out? Cheers.

Comment: You should post the code here, it is part of SO guideline to make a good question. State better what is your problem and what you really need to achieved. For example, what sort-in-place algorithm are you implementing? why do you need to implement it yourself instead of just using some library?

Comment: `DataArray[i + 1]` will access array out of bounds when `i=3`....

Comment: It's part of an exercise in my University, but there are no monitors, so I gotta do it myself.

Comment: Are repeating values permitted in the array?

Comment: Uhum, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this version?

```
int *next=DataArray;
int *end=DataArray+N;
for(pt=DataArray; pt<end; pt++) {
    if(*pt<*next) next=pt;        // find smallest
}
for(last=next, next=null; last!=null; last=next, next=null ) {
    for(pt=DataArray; pt<end; pt++) {
        if(*pt==*last)            // print all current smallest
            printf("%d: %d\n", pt-DataArray, *pt);
        else if(*pt>*last && (next==null || *pt<*next))
            next=pt;              // find next greater smallest
    }
}
```

Comment: `last=next` next contains the next value that has to be shown. Initially the smallest. `next=null` must be set to null to find the next greater value in the loop (the smallest greater than *last)  `last!=null` the loop condition. If no next value was found last will be null and the loop ends. `last=next, next=null` after every loop the next greater value ist set to the current and the next pointer set to null to find the next greater value.
It would be better to rename `last` to `current`

Comment: I've been working on this a whole week, and clearly your code is way smarter than mine. I know this isn't recommended but, yeah, thanks. It made my day to take this off my mind a little.